# Accessor functions in elisp

Tags: lisp, elisp

I'm writing some simple emacs tools for visual studio solutions.

I've got a function `sln-process-csproj-file`.  This function takes the path to a project, and returns a tuple that's just a data model of the innards of the project.

Right now the return value on the last line of that function is `` `(,project-name ,project-path ,project-files) ``.

I have written three getter functions to use with the list:

```
(defun sln-project-name (project)
  (nth 0 project))

(defun sln-project-path (project)
  (nth 1 project))

(defun sln-project-files (project)
  (nth 2 project))
```

Does this getter and setter boilerplate code match best practices? Is there a shorter way to write it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, it can be shortened by using [`defstruct`](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/cl/Structures.html). An example from the docs:

```
      (cl-defstruct person name age sex)
      (setq dave (make-person :name "Dave" :sex 'male))
           ⇒ [cl-struct-person "Dave" nil male]
      (setq other (copy-person dave))
           ⇒ [cl-struct-person "Dave" nil male]
      (eq dave other)
           ⇒ nil
      (eq (person-name dave) (person-name other))
           ⇒ t
      (person-p dave)
           ⇒ t
      (person-p [1 2 3 4])
           ⇒ nil
      (person-p "Bogus")
           ⇒ nil
      (person-p '[cl-struct-person counterfeit person object])
           ⇒ t
```

Alternatively, if you want something more heavy weight, there is a [CLOS-like object system](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_mono/eieio.html).